# PreparedStatement não Inicializa(stm = >"stm" is not a known variable in the current context.<)

Tags: java

PreparedStatement declarado não inicializa
Tem um erro na linha 83, o stm declarado na linha 21 não é inicializado.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Rascunho {

    // DAO
    private static String URL;
    private static Connection conn;
    private static PreparedStatement stm;
    private static ResultSet rs;
    private static String USER;
    private static String PASSWORD;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL = "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/c:\\Users\\Vagner\\Desktop\\Java2014\\DB\\CLINICA.FDB";
        USER = "SYSDBA";
        PASSWORD = "masterkey";

        WDB_Conecta();

        //****************************************************************
        if (Cliente_Existe(1) == 0) {
//Rotinas de salvamento
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente NÂO Existe");
        } else {
//Rotinas de Atualização
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente Existe");
        }
        //****************************************************************


        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors.toString(), e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    private static void WDB_Conecta() {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Iniciando Conecção");

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado com Sucesso");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors.toString(), e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }



    private static int Cliente_Existe(int iCodigo) {
        int bol = 0;
        String SQL;

        SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM TBCLIENTE WHERE TBCLIENTE.CODIGO = ?)";

        try {
            stm = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            stm.setInt(1, iCodigo);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();

            if (rs.getInt("TOTAL") > 0) {
                bol = 1;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errors.toString(), e.getMessage(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        return bol;
    }


}//FIM
```

Comment: Qual é a linha 83? Que erro dá?

Comment: Há a possibilidade da query estar com algum erro, não retornando um statement válido.

Comment: O meu compilador aceita o seu código. Para mim, a linha 83 é o `stm.setInt(1, iCodigo);` e há 6 linhas precedendo o primeiro `import`, correto? Já te mostraram o parênteses sobrando no seu SQL, e sem saber mais detalhes sobre a estrutura do seu banco de dados, não dá para te dar uma resposta muito melhor que isso. Além disso, você está programando de forma procedural com variáveis globais, o que não é um estilo de programação muito apreciado, especialmente em java. Tente estudar melhor um pouco de programação orientada a objetos. E a sua `URL` só vai funcionar no seu PC, o que é ruim.

Comment: Obrigado Victor, era a query mesmo, o MUTLEY printou a Query para mim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM TBCLIENTE WHERE TBCLIENTE.CODIGO = ?)";`

O `)` realmente devia estar no final da query? Acho que é este o problema.

Comment: Era o parenteses mesmo, muito Obrigado, não tinha percebido, problema Resolvido.